# JavaScript Debugging tools

Tags: javascript, jquery, debugging

I'm working with a project that came from other developer. I have a problem when it comes to some pages with a plugin that uses js/jquery. The problem is that there is an error when I look to chrome dev tools.

> ncaught TypeError: $(...).retina is not a function

I am sure that this problem arises because the script didn't continue until it loaded the JQuery function. My question is how can I figure out which script contains the error and where the stop is. There are so many script to check. Is there a easy way? A tools or what so ever.

Comment: Yes, you can use JSHint. It can help you verify your JS. I would suggest using http://jsFiddle.net, the JSHint feature there has helped me a lot in producing better code and finding errors in my syntax.

Comment: most IDE's have a find in file feature. But for starters take an inventory of the script tags and see if anything resembles `retina`. If it's not included it needs to be, or a common problem is loading jQuery more than once

Comment: Sounds like you simply haven't included the *"retina"* plugin, probably this one ~ https://github.com/tylercraft/jQuery-Retina

Comment: @charlietfl or if using OS X / *nix ~ `find . -type f -exec grep ".retina(" {} \; -print`

Comment: Simply open the developer tools, go to the "Sources" and click on the little "Pause" sign in the far right (it's inside an octogon / stop sign).  When it's active it's blue.  This turns on the "pause on exceptions" mode.  Then reload the page, leaving the tools open.  The tools will take you right to the line in question.  Then you can click on the "play" button to continue on.

Comment: @Twisty i think jshint/jsFiddle is not possible here, because i have too many plugins and maybe one of those have confilct.

Comment: @J.Aries this isn't a jsHint problem. There are a few very common problems that cause this error. the function doesn't exist on the jQuery object when it is being called